Regulating current for VFD filament
I have an older VFD of sentimental value, so I cant risk burning it. I need something modern yet decently simple to control the power to it and make sure it never exceeds whatever rating, lets say 3V/200mA, because around these values it started visibly glowing. Also, it would be nice to have it adjustable, because I'm still not sure about brightness/lifetime/etc.
First I thought about tiny DC/DC converter like Y4183, but I dont quite trust the quality of these...
Then LM317 as voltage regulator - simple, but the pot could break, sending full input voltage (12V).
Then LM317 as current regulator - probably a better choice, but the pot needs to handle the full current; or alternatively something like this or modified (falstad) - seems to work decently well, but is a lot of discrete components which can fail.
I also considered PWM (with H-bridge for additional symmetry), but I don't want to bet on the uC not freezing/crashing...
Maybe like 4-5 series diodes placed in parallel with the filament, to clamp the voltage? Coupled with some input or output resistor on the regulator to prevent too high current through the diodes?
Maybe a 5V relay, which should trigger at somewhat lower voltage (3-4V) and save the filament in case of big increase?
Here are some pictures of the VFD, I could not find any datasheet with that name (NEC FIP12CEM7). The wires seem pretty symmetric, though placed a bit uneven...

First, is the filament AC or DC? This matters. If you energize an AC filament with DC or vice-versa the brightness will be uneven.
Let’s assume your filament is DC. Probably the easiest and safest way to light it up is to use a 5V phone charger supply, and add series current limiting to it. You can use a 2-transistor current limiter for example. The charger supply works well because its secondary is floating, allowing the filament to correctly biased at cathode voltage.
If your cathode bias is just GND or lifted a bit with a diode, then you don’t need the floating supply. Just use the 2-transistor current limiter.
AC drive needs a bit more work, but it can be done.
Another idea: use an NTC surge suppressor. This will limit the cold-filament startup current.

I'm not sure about AC or DC. It comes from an old CD player. I couldn't find any datasheet, but ftr on the back it says NEC FIP12CEM7 and NO. 4 - 21 JAPAN. I tested it with DC and couldn't see any sideways brightness difference with Ua=Ug=12V (relative to one end of filament).

Ok, so probably DC then. What cathode / anode / grid voltages do you intend to use?

With anodes and grids at 12V it seems a bit dim, but usable. I also thought about using a boost converter (I have CN6009 so up to ~40V); the drivers I bought are MIC2981 (replacement for discontinued UDN2981) so possible up to 50V. Is it recommended to have grids voltage lower than anodes?
As for cathode, I don't see any problem with one end grounded, but maybe can add a diode for offset. Filament voltage seems to be around 3V when it starts visibly glowing.
Not sure whether I should power everything from 5V or 12V...
I will add a photo in the post.

If it's from a CD player it probably uses -30V for Vee, compatible with this type of IC: https://www.renesas.com/en/document/dst/upd16312-data-sheet

So probably you could use +24V for anode and lift the cathode up a few volts with a Zener diode, so that the grids can go more negative than cathode and ensure a complete pinch-off.

I will mark it as accepted, because this was generally the most useful answer in total. I haven't yet tested everything, but in case of any trouble, I will ask again or post new questions.

You could add an over-voltage crowbar circuit to protect your VFD. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowbar_(circuit) Search for it, there are many more designs. Years ago, they made a crowbar IC to be used with an SCR, but I haven't seen them in a long time.

The issue isn't the voltage. The filament will have a low resistance when cold, so it's helpful to limit its current at startup to prevent blowing it out.

Here's a current source adjustable (with potentiometer R3) between 0A and 0.5A:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Even if MOSFET M1 dies short-circuit, it is physically incapable of applying more than 5V across the load (labelled "filament"), slightly less in fact, since R4 will develop some voltage too.
R6 ensures that even if R3's wiper is disconnected (dirty perhaps), \$I_{OUT}\$ drops to zero. The potentiometer carries well under 1mA.
The op-amp must have rail-to-rail inputs and output, to work at the high-side like this.
Diode D1 and its periphery produces a potential \$V_X\$ at node X between +3.9V and +5V, and \$I_{OUT}\$ is calculated as follows:
$$ I_{OUT} = \frac{5 - V_X}{R_4} $$

Here's a much simpler design, able to source up to about 500mA:

simulate this circuit
The resistor values are appropriate for a 5V supply only. Again using a limited supply voltage, this is incapable of applying more than about 4.3V across the load. It's not a very good regulator, being quite temperature dependent, but it should maintain current within 20mA or so of the "set" value, as load resistance changes.

Thank you for this circuit! It seems really interesting, even if not practical for me (because of number of components and their peculiarity)
